# How to give a textbox focus for keyPress and typeKeys

Tags: selenium-ide

If I use typeKeys or keyPress with the target being a textbox, then nothing happens if the textbox does not have focus. How do I give focus to the textbox?

E.G. The following should delete a character from my_textbox, but it only works if I manually click on the textbox before running it.

```
<tr>
  <td>keyPress</td>
  <td>css=#my_textbox</td>
  <td>\8</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the command `focus` just before your `keyPress` command.

Answer (score 1):

1.focus | css=#my_textbox                                                                2.keypress | css=#my_textbox | \8

try out this one